# Rudder ncf-builder authentication

Tags: rudder

Whenever I try to edit or make new Techniques in the Rudder web interface I get this error:

> An Error occured! Unknown internal error during technique writing
>   Details: Cause: expected string or buffer Traceback (most recent call
>   last): File "/usr/share/ncf/api/ncf_api_flask_app/views.py", line 154,
>   in create_technique ncf.write_technique(technique,path) File
>   "/usr/share/ncf/tools/ncf.py", line 606, in write_technique content =
>   generate_technique_content(technique_metadata, methods) File
>   "/usr/share/ncf/tools/ncf.py", line 499, in generate_technique_content
>   check = ncf_constraints.check_parameter(arg, arg_constraint) File
>   "/usr/share/ncf/tools/ncf_constraints.py", line 121, in
>   check_parameter if re.search(r'[$@][{(][$@{(a-zA-Z0-9[]_.-]+[})]',
>   parameter_value) is not None : File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line
>   146, in search return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
>   TypeError: expected string or buffer

I've already configured everything according to the manual, including setting up ncf-builder. Whenever I open the /localhost/ncf-builder it says that I'm not authenticated.

Comment: Which documentation did you follow to setup ncf-builder, and which version of Rudder have you installed? It looks like the technique you are trying to save is not valid, what is the content of this technique (the generic methods and the parameters you used)?

Comment: I've installed the 3.2 verison and used http://www.ncf.io/pages/ncf-builder.html this with the Quickstart guide. Couldn't find anything else.
I just tried to create a new user using the template techniques to test if it works.

btw just checked their demo: https://demo.rudder-project.org/
The same problems come up whenever I try to do the same as on my server.

Comment: Rudder comes with ncf and its technique editor (install packages ncf and ncf-api-virtualenv), you should not have to do anything to access. The documentation on ncf.io is when you want to use ncf as standalone.

Comment: By default, ncf-builder authenticate using cookies generated by Rudder, so if you open directly /localhost/ncf-builder without having an open tab with Rudder it will fail

Comment: As Alexis said, there may be and invalid technique file either in /var/rudder/configuration-repository/ncf/50_techniques or /usr/share/ncf/tree/50_techniques, try deleting this file (or moving it ... and i will be interested if you can show it's content in a gist !! )